# Is there any obvious methods or restructuring I should consider to speed up macro?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a a macro that loops through 37,000 rows of an excel file to try and find a matching file name in a synced sharepoint file system (Year folders and sub-quarter folders). The conditions are as follows -

1. If a file is found, add the file information to the respective row.
2. If a file is not found, print "Not Found" in the respective row.
3. If a duplicate file is found in any of the folders (could be same folder) only add the information of the most recent file found based on the files modified timestamp.

Currently this macro takes over 13 hours to run to completion.

Is there anything I can do to help speed it up?

---

```
Sub RecursiveLoop(folderPath As String, ws As Worksheet)
    Dim fs As Object
    Dim folder As Object
    Dim subfolder As Object
    Dim subsubfolder As Object
    Dim file As Object
    Dim subfolderPath As String
    Dim currentRow As Long
    Dim excelFileName As String
    Dim found As Boolean
    Dim recentFiles As New Dictionary ' Create a dictionary to store recent files
    

    spaddress = "/test/"

    Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set folder = fs.GetFolder(folderPath)

    For Each subfolder In folder.SubFolders ' Loop through year subfolders
        subfolderPath = subfolder.Path
        For Each subsubfolder In subfolder.SubFolders ' Loop through quarter subfolders
            found = False ' Reset the found flag for each quarter subfolder
            ' Clear the recentFiles dictionary for each sub-subfolder
            Set recentFiles = New Dictionary
            
            For i = 3 To ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "M").End(xlUp).Row
                excelFileName = ws.Cells(i, "M").Value
                For Each file In subsubfolder.Files
                    If InStr(1, file.Name, GetFileNameWithoutExtension(excelFileName), vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
                        ' Check if this is the most recent file for this excelFileName
                        If Not recentFiles.Exists(excelFileName) Then
                            ' If the file is not in the dictionary, add it
                            Set recentFiles(excelFileName) = file
                        ElseIf file.DateLastModified > recentFiles(excelFileName).DateLastModified Then
                            ' If the file is more recent, update the dictionary entry
                            Set recentFiles(excelFileName) = file
                        End If
                    End If
                Next file
                
                ' Process the most recent file for this excelFileName
                If recentFiles.Exists(excelFileName) Then
                    Set recentFile = recentFiles(excelFileName)
                    ws.Cells(i, "J").Value = "Approved by " & GetTrailingName(recentFile.Name, GetFileNameWithoutExtension(excelFileName))
                    pdfLink = Replace(excelFileName, " ", "%20")
                    If ws.Cells(i, "H") <> "" And ws.Cells(i, "E") = "" Then
                        ws.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=ws.Cells(i, "K"), Address:=spaddress & recentFile.Name, TextToDisplay:="link"
                    ElseIf ws.Cells(i, "E") <> "" And ws.Cells(i, "H") = "" Then
                        ws.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=ws.Cells(i, "L"), Address:=spaddress & recentFile.Name, TextToDisplay:="link"
                    ElseIf ws.Cells(i, "E") <> "" And ws.Cells(i, "H") <> "" Then
                        ws.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=ws.Cells(i, "K"), Address:=spaddress & recentFile.Name, TextToDisplay:="link"
                    End If
                End If
                
                found = True ' Mark as found if the file is found
            Next i
        Next subsubfolder
    Next subfolder

    Set fs = Nothing
    Set folder = Nothing
    Set subfolder = Nothing
    Set subsubfolder = Nothing
    Set file = Nothing
End Sub
```

---

I was hoping the code would take less than 12 hours....

Comment: have you considered using Power Query to pull the file metadata from SharePoint into Excel? Then you can use that query for analysis in pivot tables etc.  without vba looping, which is always slow.

Comment: I wonder if it might make sense to pull your file info into an array and sort it by file stem and modified date. Scan the array and delete duplicates, keeping the path for the most recent file. You could then compare your M column to the array one time instead of looping through 37,000 rows for each subfolder. Not sure, but seems worth looking into.

Comment: I don't think this is  doing what you said in point number 3, because your are clearing the `recentFiles` dictionary with each subfolder. It may work coincidentally, because of convenient folder naming conventions presenting the most recent file last.  Again, just a cursory review, so I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: @teylyn I did not even think of that. Do you think I could get everything I need from the metadata?

Comment: How many files are there in total?  Are the names in the Excel listing all substrings of the actual file names?  How long does it take to loop over all the files and collect the names?  Some examples of your Excel data and corresponding file names would help here

Comment: @TimWilliams only 2,000 files are currently in the SharePoint folders. This will grow over time. Yes, the Excel listings are all substrings of actual file names. The Excel file name is a workday export, so its pre-generated for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not fully fleshed-out, but should give you some ideas:

```vb
Sub Tester()
    
    Dim FileInfo, t, i As Long, n As Long, rngFiles As Range, ws As Worksheet
    Dim arrNames, nm As String, fso As Object, idx As Long, dt, rw As Range
    t = Timer
    
    FileInfo = AllFileInfo("C:\Temp\VBA\Test", "*.xls*")
    Debug.Print Timer - t, "Found " & UBound(FileInfo, 1) & " Excel files"
    
    Set ws = ActiveSheet        'for example
    Set rngFiles = ws.Range("M3:M" & ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "M").End(xlUp).Row)
    arrNames = rngFiles.Value   'get all listed file names as an array
    Set fso = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
    
    For i = 1 To UBound(arrNames, 1) 'loop all names from the worksheet
        nm = arrNames(i, 1)
        If Len(nm) > 0 Then
            nm = CStr(fso.GetBaseName(nm))
            idx = 0 'reset FileInfo match position
            
            For n = 1 To UBound(FileInfo, 1) 'loop over file info array
                If InStr(1, FileInfo(n, 1), nm, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
                    If idx = 0 Then
                        idx = n 'first match found
                    Else
                        'switch position if this file is newer
                        If FileInfo(n, 3) > FileInfo(idx, 3) Then idx = n
                    End If
                End If
            Next n
            
            If idx > 0 Then
                Set rw = rngFiles.Cells(i).EntireRow ' row to work on
                '.....
                'add the file info to the row
                '.....
            End If
        End If
    Next i
    Debug.Print Timer - t, "Checked against worksheet '" & ws.Name & "'"
End Sub

'Return an array of file info given a starting folder and a file pattern
'  e.g. "*.txt"
Function AllFileInfo(startFolder As String, filePattern As String) As Variant

    Dim fso As Object, fldr As Object, f, subFldr As Object, subSubFldr As Object, fpath
    Dim colFiles As New Collection, arr, n As Long
    
    Set fso = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
    Set fldr = fso.GetFolder(startFolder)
    For Each subFldr In fldr.subFolders           'years
        For Each subSubFldr In subFldr.subFolders 'quarters
            fpath = subSubFldr.Path
            If Right(fpath, 1) <> "\" Then fpath = fpath & "\"
            f = Dir(fpath & filePattern) 'Dir is faster...
            Do While Len(f) > 0
                colFiles.Add fso.GetFile(fpath & f)
                f = Dir()
            Loop
        Next subSubFldr
    Next subFldr
    ReDim arr(1 To colFiles.Count, 1 To 3) 'size the output array
    For n = 1 To colFiles.Count            'loop to fill
        With colFiles(n)
            arr(n, 1) = fso.GetBaseName(.Name) 'no extension
            arr(n, 2) = .Path                  'full path
            arr(n, 3) = .DateLastModified      'mod date
        End With
    Next n
    AllFileInfo = arr
End Function
```

Looping over a folder structure is relatively slow, so you should do that *once* and store the information on the found files in something you can quickly search over.  I'm just using a nested loop, but I think it will be still much faster than your current approach.

Picking up info on 2000 files took about 6 seconds, and the nested loop ran for about a minute (without any sheet updates, so add a little bit more for that...)

**EDIT** - the nested loop could maybe be optimized more, but you'd need to provide more details on (eg) whether the file names from the sheet all match the *beginning* of the file names from the folders, or if they are somewhere else in the folder file names.
Eg:
Searched name "File1.xlsx" matches "File1 Jeff.xlsx" and "File1 Jane.xlsx" (match on beginning of name) or is it more like "BlahBlah File1 Jeff.xlsx", "BlahBlah File1 Jane.xlsx" (match somewhere in the middle of the name)

Comment: Match the beginning of the file names so for example in the sheet a file is called "123_test.pdf" and the file in sharepoint folder is called "123_test_some name.pdf" and I am using the function "GetNameWithoutExtension" to find the file in sharepoint without the "some name" string. that is why duplicate files could live in the same file because the "some name" string would be different for each duplicate - Or the file could be the exact same name and just live in a separate sub -sub folder. so the code needs to only add the file info for the most recent date modified file.

Comment: Try this out and if you feel it still needs speeding up I will take a look at how that might work.

Comment: this is working incredibly fast, in the spot where I can add the file info for the row, how would I call on the file properties to add the file path to the respective cell value? for instance, I want to say "approved by" and then the full file path

Comment: The full path would be in `FileInfo(idx, 2)` .  The file name (without the extension) is in  `FileInfo(idx, 1)`

Answer (score 0):

NOTES:

1. **This code has not been tested**, because I don't have your `GetFileNameWithoutExtension()` and `GetTrailingName()` functions, nor do I have your data or file structure. It may contain basic syntax errors, logic errors, etc. Use this as a guide for working through your solution.
2. Neither this nor your solution is recursive. Naming the function `RecursiveLoop` is both misleading and non-informative. I recommend `SetFileLinks` or something of that nature.
3. I simplified the column choices of K and L for the link by looking only at the H column, because I believe your code does essentially the same thing. If your code was meant to do something else, you might need to make adjustments here as well.
4. I am uncertain about your choice of Hyperlink Address being `spAddress & file.Name`. It seems to me that it should be `file.Path`. I chose not to correct that, because you could be doing something interesting.
5. I have assumed that `GetFileNameWithoutExtension(excelFilename)` produces the same result as `fs.GetBaseName(file.Path)`. That may not be true. If it is not true, this code will definitely not work. You will need to fix the code that sets `baseFileName` so that it matches whatever `GetFileNameWithoutExtension(excelFilename)` produces.
6. I put "Not Found" in column "N", because you did not provide a spreadsheet example and did not specify where it should go. To put it in a different column, change the value of `COLUMN_NOTFOUND`.
7. I have no idea if this is actually faster. However, it seems theoretically faster because it is doing less looping in VBA. I think (if I recall my Big O notation correctly) this would be something like Om+n rather than Omn which your original code is. I leave it to more informed people than I to decide if I'm correct on that.

With all that, here is one proposed solution:

```
Sub RecursiveLoop(folderPath As String, ws As Worksheet)

    Const COLUMN_FILENAME As String = "M"
    Const COLUMN_APPROVAL As String = "J"
    Const COLUMN_NOTFOUND As String = "N"
    
    Dim fs As Object
    Dim folder As Object
    Dim subFolder As Object
    Dim subSubFolder As Object
    Dim file As Object
    
    Dim baseFileName As String
    Dim currentRow As Long
    Dim excelFileName As String
    Dim recentFiles As Dictionary ' Create a dictionary to store recent files
    Dim rowCount As Long
    Dim spAddress As String
    
    spAddress = "/test/"

    ' Initialize the file system and dictionary
    Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set folder = fs.GetFolder(folderPath)
    Set recentFiles = New Dictionary

    ' Get a collection of all files, keeping only the most recent file if the filename is duplicated.
    For Each subFolder In folder.SubFolders ' Loop through year subfolders
        For Each subSubFolder In subFolder.SubFolders ' Loop through quarter subfolders
            For Each file In subSubFolder.Files
                baseFileName = fs.GetBaseName(file.Path)
                
                ' Store the most recently modified file
                If Not recentFiles.Exists(baseFileName) Then
                    Set recentFiles(baseFileName) = file
                ElseIf file.DateLastModified > recentFiles(baseFileName).DateLastModified Then
                    Set recentFiles(baseFileName) = file
                End If
            Next 'file
        Next 'subSubFolder
    Next 'subFolder

    ' Get a count of rows containing filenames
    rowCount = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, COLUMN_FILENAME).End(xlUp).Row - 2
    
    ' Go through each row and see if the file exists.
    For currentRow = 3 To rowCount
    
        ' Get the full filename from the filename column.
        excelFileName = ws.Cells(currentRow, COLUMN_FILENAME).Value
       
        ' See if the name without the extension is in the dictionary.
        If recentFiles.Exists(GetFileNameWithoutExtension(excelFileName)) Then
            
            ' It is, so get a handle to it.
            Set file = recentFiles(GetFileNameWithoutExtension(excelFileName))
            
            ' Extract the approver's name from the file name.
            ws.Cells(currentRow, COLUMN_APPROVAL).Value = "Approved by " & GetTrailingName(file.Name, GetFileNameWithoutExtension(excelFileName))
            
            ' Put a link in K or L depending on whether or not something is in column H. (What does this mean?)
            If ws.Cells(currentRow, "H") <> "" Then
                ws.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=ws.Cells(currentRow, "K"), Address:=spAddress & file.Name, TextToDisplay:="link"
            Else
                ws.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=ws.Cells(currentRow, "L"), Address:=spAddress & file.Name, TextToDisplay:="link"
            End If
        Else
            ' The file doesn't exist, so put "Not Found" in the NOT FOUND column.
            ws.Cells(i, COLUMN_NOTFOUND).Value = "Not Found"
        End If
        
    Next 'currentRow

    ' Cleanup
    Set fs = Nothing
    Set folder = Nothing
    Set subFolder = Nothing
    Set subSubFolder = Nothing
    Set file = Nothing
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your input, I will test it out when I get a chance.